# How to Split the elements of arraylist and store it in Set to avoid Duplicacy

Tags: java, android

I want to Split my data from the Arraylist which is coming as A,B,C,B,E,A

i want to split it and store it into the HashSet so that i can avoid the Duplicates.

```
for (int i = 0;i<tableAnswers.size();i++){
                TableAnswers t = tableAnswers.get(i);
                try {
                    String[] a1 = t.getAns1().split(",");
                    String[] a2 = t.getAns2().split(",");
                    String[] a3 = t.getAns3().split(",");
                    String[] a4 = t.getAns4().split(",");
                    aa1.add(new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(a1)));
                }catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
```

The Result is giving me different indexes for the Same Value.
What i may be doing wrong.?

Comment: can you give your input and desired output?

Comment: What is the purpose of `aa1`, and when are you only adding the first answer's data to it?

Comment: if aa1 is an array list, then you might get duplicates if you insert a2, a3, a4 into aa1 afterwards.

Comment: i have a arraylist with elements {A,B,C,B,E,A},{B,A,C,A,E},{A,C,E,A,C}..and so on... now i need to break this into single elements like A,B,C,B,E,A,B,A,C,A,E,A,C,E,A,C. lastly, i want to apply Set so that i can avoid duplicates.

Comment: just change aa1 to a hashset. and use aa1.addAll(Arrays.asList(a1)); //repeat for a2 to a4

Comment: @Angle Koh..i tried your answer too. your answer provided is more accurate than provided by rahul. now i am getting the exact result. Thank you both of you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>;
list.add("a");
list.add("b");
list.add("a");
list.add("b");

String stringArray = Arrays.toString(list.toArray()); 
String commaSepratedValues = stringArray.replaceAll("[","").replaceAll("]","");
for(String value : commaSepratedValues.split(",")){
    //here you can add it to SET<>
}
```

Comment: I modified this Code a bit. using Array.toString(); , it made the result work as i needed.